# Find all linear maps (all 3x3 matrices) whose img(A) is spanned by <1 1 1>, <-1 0 1> and ker(A) is spanned by <-1 2 0>

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have to find all linear maps (all 3x3 matrices) such that:

$$ img(A) = span (\left(\begin{array}{crc}
 1 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}\right), 
\left(\begin{array}{crc}
 -1 \\
 0 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}\right))
$$

and

$$ ker(A) = span (\left(\begin{array}{crc}
 -1 \\
 2 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}\right))$$

I am at a loss.

I need to understand how this works. Please help!

I don't undertsand the answer below. Can someone explain in a different way?

EDIT:

let $A$ be the matrix of transformation $T$.

let $v1$ be the vector $$ v1 =\left(\begin{array}{crc}
 -1 \\
 2 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}\right)$$.

Let $v1,v2,v3$ for a basis for $R^3$ and $v2,v3$ be vectors so that the image of the transformation is the vectors are

$$ w2 =\left(\begin{array}{crc}
 1 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}\right)$$.

$$ w3 =\left(\begin{array}{crc}
 -1 \\
 0 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}\right)$$.

Because $v1,v2,v3$  for a basis then the matrix $A$ can be represented by:

$$ A =\left(\begin{array}{crc}
 ..&..&.. \\
 T(v1)& T(v2)&T(v3) \\
 ..&..&.. \\
\end{array}\right)$$.

we know that the $T(v1)=0, T(v2)=w2 and T(v3)=w3$

so the matrix should be this

$$ w3 =\left(\begin{array}{crc}
 0&1& -1 \\
 0& 1&0 \\
 0&1&1 \\
\end{array}\right)$$.

But this seems to be wrong

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: For the matrix of a linear map with _respect to given bases at entry and at exit_ the columns hold the coordinates, with respect to the basis at exit, of the images _of the basis vectors at entry_. Here you want the matrix with respect to the _standard_ basis (at entry and exit) so you cannot directly use $T(v_j)$ as columns. Instead you can _solve_ the matrix entries from $A\cdot v_1=0$ etc, or compute the necessary change of basis (which in the end amounts to the same computation).

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $$ B:=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$
has the desired image, 
$$ C:=\begin{pmatrix}2&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
has the desired kernel. You might want to look at 
$$ A=B\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}C$$
for suitable $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. Matrix B is just the vectors of the span of the image. Where did you get matrix C from?

Comment: @Nash $a,b,c,d$ are not completely arbitrary. As an extreme example, what happens if $a=b=c=d=0$?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note the the requirements of an image of dimension$~2$ and a kernel of dimension$~1$ are compatible for a linear map defined on a space of dimension$~3$, by the rank-nullity theorem, so the set of such matrices is not going to be empty. If start with the given single vector spanning the kernel (call it $v_1$), you can extend it in many ways with two more vectors $v_2,v_3$ to a basis, for instance by the first and third standard basis vector. Now $v_1$ must map to zero, and the image of $A$ will be spanned by the images of $v_2,v_3$. You can therefore choose any pair of linearly independent vectors $w_2,w_3$ of the specified image subspace as images of $v_2,v_3$, and solve for the matrix $A$ such that $A\cdot v_1=0$ and $A\cdot v_i=w_i$ for $i=2,3$.

That gives a somewhat messy procedure though, requiring to solve for $A$ for every pair of vectors spanning the image, so you can clean it up as follows. Your map must have rank$~2$, so you can split it into first a map with image $\Bbb R^2$, and then a linear map $\Bbb R^2$ with the specified image. For the first step you can choose to send $v_1\mapsto 0$, $v_2\mapsto e_1$ and $v_3\mapsto e_2$, where $e_1,e_2$ are standard basis vectors of$~\Bbb R^2$. Here you must solve for a $2\times3$ matrix, but you need to do this only once; the solution is:
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}1&\frac12&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
(the result depends on my choice for $v_2,v_3$ of course; having chosen standard basis vectors made the solution process rather easy: the first ald third column were immediately given). Now we must compose with a map sending $\Bbb R^2$ to the specified image injectively; one such map is obviously the one with matrix
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix},
$$
so
$$
 A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}
 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}1&\frac12&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}1&\frac12&-1\\1&\frac12&0\\1&\frac12&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
is one solution. But you must also cater for other pairs of vectors spanning the given image. These pair are linear combinations of the given column vectors, which can be found as the columns of the product
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}
 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}a&c\\b&d\end{pmatrix}
$$
where the matrix on the right must be invertible (otherwise the product would not have rank$~2$: the vectors formed would be linearly dependent). So now you find the *general* solution as a matrix product
$$
 A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}
 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}a&c\\b&d\end{pmatrix}
 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}1&\frac12&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix},
$$
just ike in the answer by Hagen von Eitzen.

Comment: Isn't the kernels dimension $1$?

Comment: @Nash: Yes, that was a typo; thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to understand it! :)

Comment: Have you computed the matrix???

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem about number triples and matrices. We are not allowed to introduce some new basis at our liking. (By the way, in your edit you mix up the coordinate representation of the vectors $w_1$, etc., with respect to different bases.)

The matrices $A$ fulfilling the stated conditions will have to have rank $2$. All three columns of $A$ (the images of the standard basis vectors) have to be linear combinations of the two given image-spanning vectors. Therefore $A$ has to be of the form
$$A=\left[\matrix{1&-1\cr 1&0\cr 1&1\cr}\right]\>
\left[\matrix{c_{11}&c_{12}&c_{13}\cr c_{21}&c_{22}&c_{23}\cr}\right]=
\left[\matrix{c_{11}-c_{21}&c_{12}-c_{22}&c_{13}-c_{23}\cr c_{11}&c_{12}&c_{13}\cr
c_{11}+c_{21}&c_{12}+c_{22}&c_{13}+c_{23}\cr }\right]\ ,$$
where the matrix $C$ producing three arbitrary linear combinations of the image-spanning vectors has to have rank $2$. Now we have to make sure that the matrix appearing on the right annihilates the vector $[-1\ 2\ 0]^\top$. This leads to the equations
$$c_{11}=2c_{12},\quad c_{21}=2 c_{22}\ .$$
Therefore the matrices $A$ we are looking for are parametrized by
$$A=\left[\matrix{2(c_{12}-c_{22})&c_{12}-c_{22}&c_{13}-c_{23}\cr 2c_{12}&c_{12}&c_{13}\cr
2(c_{12}+c_{22})&c_{12}+c_{22}&c_{13}+c_{23}\cr }\right]\ ,$$
and we have the extra condition 
$$c_{12}c_{23}-c_{13} c_{22}\ne0\ ,$$ which assures that ${\rm rank}(A)=2$.

Comment: can you look a my edit please? thanks :)